# CFML registration form troubles -- correct use of encodeForHTMLAttribute?

Tags: forms, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

Lucee 5.2

MS SQL Server 2014

Hi, friends,

I need some help with a CFML task -- this is a conference registration form for a client.

In the code below, am I using encodeForHTMLAttribute correctly? I have been doing some research on encodeForHTMLAttribute -- for example, https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforhtmlattribute.html -- but I am not sure a) if I am using it correctly, or b) if I even need to use it at all.

Does the CFML below look reasonable? Thank you as always for your help.

Eric

```
<!--- begin CFOUTPUT for user input fields --->
<cfoutput>
<li>
<label for="Title"><h3>Title (Ms., Mr., Dr. etc.):</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Title" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.Title,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="1" size="70" autofocus="true" />
</li>

<li>
<label for="x_first_name"><h3>First Name:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_first_name,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="2" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Enter First Name</span>
</li>

<li>
<label for="MiddleInitial"><h3>Middle Initial:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="MiddleInitial" placeholder="MI" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.MiddleInitial,255)))#" maxlength="5" tabindex="3" size="1" />
</li>

<li>
<label for="x_last_name"><h3>Last Name:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_last_name,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="4" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Enter Last Name</span> 
</li>

<li>
  <label for="Credentials"><h3>Credentials:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="Credentials" placeholder="Credentials (e.g. RN, MSN, PhD, MD)" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.Credentials,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="5" size="70" required="yes" />
     <span class="form_hint">Credentials (e.g. RN, MSN, PhD, MD)</span> 
</li>

<li>
<label for="x_company"><h3>Current Position and Organization:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_company" placeholder="Current Position and Organization" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_company,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="6" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Enter Current Position and Organization</span>               
</li>

<li>
<label for="x_address"><h3>Address:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_address" placeholder="Please enter your address" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_address,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="7" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Please enter your mailing address</span> 
</li>

<li>
<label for="x_city"><h3>City:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_city" placeholder="Please enter your city" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_city,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="8" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Please enter your city</span> 
</li>

<li>
  <label for="x_state"><h3>State or Province:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_state" placeholder="Please enter your State or Province" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_state,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="9" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Please enter your State or Province</span>             
</li>                     


<li>
<label for="x_zip"><h3>ZIP or Postal Code:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_zip" placeholder="Please enter your ZIP or Postal Code" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_zip,25)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="10" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Please enter your ZIP or Postal Code</span>               
</li> 

           <li>
<label for="x_country"><h3>Country:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_country" placeholder="Please enter your country" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_country,255)))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="11" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Please enter your country</span>                
</li>  

           <li>
<label for="TelephoneWork"><h3>Work Telephone:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="TelephoneWork" placeholder="Please enter your work telephone number" value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.TelephoneWork,25)))#" maxlength="25" tabindex="13" size="70" />
        <span class="form_hint">Please enter your work telephone number.</span> 
</li>     

<li>
<label for="x_email"><h3>email address:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_email" placeholder="Important: Please enter your valid email address." value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.x_email,128)))#" maxlength="128" tabindex="16" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Enter Email Address</span> 
</li>

<li>
<label for="SpecialRequirements"><h3>Special Requirements -- dietary, mobility, etc.:</h3></label>

<input type="text" name="SpecialRequirements" placeholder="Important: Please enter special requirements, if any." value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.SpecialRequirements,255)))#" 
maxlength="255" tabindex="18" size="70" />

</li>
</cfoutput><!--- /CFOUTPUT for user input fields --->
```

Comment: The first two question should have been separate question on SO. The last one does not have enough info. Welcome to SO

Comment: James, I'm sorry about that! I'll be more conscientious going forward. I really appreciate your time and help. Eric

Comment: No worries. S.O. has a slightly different [model](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (q&a, one question per thread, global edits, ..) Takes a little getting used to :-)

Comment: editing a question to make it not a question is frowned upon.

Answer (score 5):

**Question 1**

When setting attributes such a value in form fields use.

```
encodeForHTMLAttribute()
```

**Question 2**

Money fields for USD should be

```
type="number" step="0.01"
```

Other currencies have different grandularity

**Question 3**

You would have to add code that describes your response page. There is not enough info to determine the problem.

Comment: James, thank you! That's really helpful.

1. So, is this how the encodeForHTMLAttribute should look?
    <input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Title" value="<cfoutput>#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Trim(Left(form.Title,255)))#</cfoutput>" maxlength="255" tabindex="1" size="70" autofocus="true" />

2. And, how does this look?
   <input type="number" step="0.01" name="OptionalDonation" placeholder="Please enter a number value only; for example, 50.00" value="<cfoutput>#OptionalDonation#</cfoutput>" size="10" />

Stack says I cannot add more text to this post?

Eric

Comment: @EricB - Personally I would use a single set of `cfoutput` tags around the whole form, instead of per field. S.O. comments are limited to a small number of characters, but you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48119748/8895292) a question to add more details. However, sounds like 3) should be a separate question altogether.

Comment: Got it. I'm gonna try this again. =)

Comment: You can create an answer for your own question.

Comment: James, I am going to edit this question, and trim it down to one question only. I'm not sure how to answer my own question; i am pretty sure I would give an incorrect reply. =)

Comment: Just for future reference. You should have left the question as is AND created an answer. As it stands no one knows what you struggled with and what was the eventual solution. Don't worry though. It takes a while to get a hang of how SO does things.

Comment: Dear James: first, thank you =) I'm getting the hang of it. I really appreciate the kindness. I've decided to concentrate on encodeForHTMLAttribute, and have been doing more research on it. I'm not completely sure I need it, and I am probably going to take it out of the application. I am working also on the other questions I originally posted and I think, after some research and testing, I'm getting closer to a solution. Thanks to all the folks who replied to my questions. I hope your weekend is going well. =)

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is, `In the code below, am I using encodeForHTMLAttribute correctly?`.  The answer is no, in that you are using it in the wrong place.

The encodeForHTMLAttribute function changes certain characters to their html equivalent.  For example, a less than symbol, `<`, becomes `&lt;`.  If you were outputting this in a display tag of a web page, such as paragraph or table detail, you would see `<`.  However, in an input tag, you would see `&lt;`  Is that what you want your users to see?

Your next question is, `Does the CFML below look reasonable?`.  The syntax is fine but the fact that it contains an html for being prepopulated from a form post strikes me as odd.  Are you making your users post the same information twice?

Comment: Dan, thank you. After doing some more reading I came to the conclusion that I do not need the encodeForHTMLAttribute function at all. I am not quite sure why it was there in the first place. I think it made sense, for some reason, at the time.

>>>> Are you making your users post the same information twice?

No, that's not my intention. These form fields are from an insert / update form; people add their information only one time.

Thank you very much for this helpful reply.

Eric

Comment: The source would show `&lt;`, but the user should still see "<".  @EricB - If the input contains special values, like quotes, etc... are one reason why you might want to use it.  https://trycf.com/gist/d26005391c415b58be8894ae54a2f5b5/lucee5?theme=monokai. Notice the first <input> does not display the value properly.

Comment: Ageax -- neat! I see that now. TryCF looks like a great tool. Thank you, yet again. Eric